# Can $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{n(\ln n)^p}$ be treated as p-series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The question is to find out whether the following series converges: $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac1{n(\ln n)^p}$$

Can this be treated as a p-series with $n\ln n$ as $x$ so it would be of the form $\dfrac1{x^p}$?

If it can't, it would help my understanding to see the reasoning, preferably with a counterexample explaining why. Thanks

Comment: $n$ isn't raised to the $p^{\text{th}}$ power, only $\log n$ is raised to the $p$. This means you can't treat the denominator as $x^p$ (although, you'll find the same conclusion as in the $\sum n^{-p}$ case).

Comment: Hint: Does the following integral converges? $\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x\ln(x)^p}$. (I'm not sure if it can be seen as a $p$-series... I suspect not, at least not in a useful way.)

Comment: The answer depends on the meaning of "treated as $p$-series". If the meaning is "be solved by the same tool (namely, integral test)" or "be convergent for the same values of $p$ (namely, $p>1$)", then the answer is yes.

Comment: @Pedro I meant the second definition you mentioned, and why is the answer yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the meaning of "treated as $p$-series".

- If the meaning is "be solved by the same tool (namely, integral test)" or "be convergent for the same values of $p$ (namely, $p>1$)", then the answer is yes.
- If the meaning is "to apply the same conclusions (without further analysis) because of algebraic similarity (namely, denominator going to infinity raised to the power $p$), then the answer is no. Counterexample:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\ln n (\ln n)^p}$$

Comment: Why is my example still convergent for the same powers of p then? just coincidental?

Comment: The same powers of $p$ work because, once you make the substitution $u = \ln x$ in the relevant integral, you find yourself considering $\int \frac{1}{u^p} du$.

Comment: suomynonA, I belive the main point was explained by @AustinMohr.

Comment: @suomynonA Details of calculation can be found in examples 1 and 2 of section 10.13 (The integral test) in  [Apostol's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=RQtRAAAAMAAJ&q=Calculus:+One-variable+calculus,+with+an+introduction+to+linear+algebra&dq=Calculus:+One-variable+calculus,+with+an+introduction+to+linear+algebra&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3laewz-zgAhWFGbkGHeNODnUQ6AEIKTAA), where both series are studied.

Comment: @AustinMohr thanks